# solving the equation ($\sin(z)/z$)

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find all set of $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the equation $\omega=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ has solutions $z$ arbitrary close to $0$.
I started with Taylor series for $\sin(z)$ but as it's infinity sum, I think that can not be correct, then I wrote the equation $\sin(z)=\frac{{e^{iz}}-{e^{-iz}}}{2i}$ and by setting $t:=e^{iz}$ I reached a quadratic equation that it can not help.
Is there any way for this problem?

Comment: You have $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$, so solutions arbitrarily close to $0$ restrict $\omega$ to $\{1\}$.

Comment: So that's the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

More generally: if $f$ is continuous at  $0$, then the existence of solutions of $f(z)=w$ arbitrarily close to $0$ implies $w=f(0)$, directly from the definition of continuity. In your example, the function is  $f(z)=\sin z/z $, extended by $f(0)=1$.

For nonconstant holomorphic functions, such as $f$ above, there is an extra twist: whatever $w$ is, the solutions of $f(z)=w$ form a discrete set: they cannot have a point of accumulation inside of the domain. Therefore, for sufficiently small $r$ the only solution of $f(z)=1$ in the $r$-neighborhood of $0$ is $z=0$.